# prevent any user that doesnot belong to an organic group, to access any node outside his group with code

Tags: 7, organic-groups

i have made the following custom module, in order to prevent any user that belongs to group 1, be able to view or edit a node that belongs to group 2. Still if one knows the url of the node, manages to view it regardless of which group he belongs to, and more important, edit it. Any resemblance to any other question posted here is just a coincidence, also to mention that each node belongs to one and only group.

What am i doing wrong in below code?

```
<?php   
    /**
     * Implements hook_node_access()
     */
    function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account){
        if($op=='view' && isset($node->og_group_ref[und])){
            $user=user_load($account->uid);
            $node_og_group_nid=$node->og_group_ref[und][0]['target_id'];
            $user_og_group_nid=$user->og_user_node[und][0]['target_id']; 
            if($node_og_group_nid!=$user_og_group_nid) return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is for the same site, with the same basic issue, that [this other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/290352/96788) is about? If so, shouldn't the contents of this question be appended to the first one?

Comment: i would rather you made a meaningful comment. My question is about a custom module i have written. I do not see how your comment helps with my code.

Comment: My comment was intended to help **you**. If your question is about the same site then you should do what I recommended. If it's not related to the first, then you really should say so. When I first saw your question, I assumed it was the same person asking about the same site, who created a new account to make it appear as if it wasn't. That would make it unlikely either question would be answered since most of the frequent users would assume the same thing. But if it was a coincidence, you needed to know about the first question, so I wrote my comment instead of just ignoring your quesrion.